# Deadlock error in inserting bulk of records to MySQL database using trigger and Qt multi threading

Tags: mysql, trigger, deadlock, multi-thread

I have a multi thread program (In this case in Qt) which every thread at a specific time, inserts 500 records in a `MySQL` table (I call that as `A_tbl`) and also there is a trigger for `A_tbl` that inserts some values to other tables (I call them as `B_tbl`s) and after that by some `select` queries in the trigger, I get the `ID`s of those inserted records in `B_tbl`s. (I think that I have to use these `select` queries and `last_insert_id()` is not useful in my case since maybe I need the `ID` of the first inserted record).

But these `select` queries along with the last `insert` query lead to this error:

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction QMYSQL3: Unable to execute statement
```

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `IpAn`.`A_tbl_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `A_tbl` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT IGNORE INTO source_names (source_name) VALUES (NEW.source_name);
INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (loc1,loc2) VALUES (NEW.loc1,NEW.loc2);

SET @source_names_id = (select id from source_names USE INDEX (PRIMARY) where source_name=NEW.source_name);
SET @locations_id = (select id from locations USE INDEX (PRIMARY) where loc1=NEW.loc1 and loc2=NEW.loc2);

INSERT IGNORE INTO sections (source_names_id,locations_id) VALUES (@source_names_id,@locations_id);

...

END
```

If I change the threads to one, the error will not occur.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @source_names_id = (select id from source_names USE INDEX (PRIMARY) where source_name=NEW.source_name);
```

-->

```
SELECT @source_names_id := id
    FROM source_names
    WHERE source_name = NEW.source_name;
```

*AND* have

```
PRIMARY KEY(id)
INDEX(source_name)
```

Do *not* use `USE INDEX(PRIMARY)` unless it is `PRIMARY KEY(source_name)`.  Even then, there is no need for `USE INDEX`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you need to discuss this further.